# Set Default option in dropdown list HTML

Tags: php, laravel

In my **create.blade.php** I have a dropdown list which is like that.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="company-content">Sexe</label>
<select name="sex" id="" class="form-control">
<option value="">Choice</option>
<option>Women</option>
<option>Man</option>
</select>
</div>
```

If I choose the option 2, that is to say the item **man**, in my **edit.blade.php** I will wish to get the item **man**.
[image]

However, when I want to change the item, my dropdown list is always on **woman** bij default. It's not practical...

Here is my code concerning the file edit.blade.php, do you have an idea please?

Thank you

[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="company-content">Sex</label>
<select name="sexe" id="" class="form-control">
<option>Women</option>
<option>Man</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**Edit:** 16/03/2019

Visibly, I should do several modifications on my Controller too?

**My function edit**

```
public function edit($id)
{
        //
  $candidats = Candidat::find($id);
  $permis = Permis::all();
  return view('admin.candidats.edit', compact('candidats', 'permis'));
}
```

**My function update**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
     $request->validate([
           'sexe' => 'required|string',
           'fk_permis' => 'required'
    ]);

      $candidats = Candidat::find($id);
      $candidats->sexe = $request->get('sexe');
      $candidats->fk_permis = $request->get('fk_permis');
      $candidats->save();
        return redirect()->route('candidats.index')
                    ->with('success', 'mise à jour effectuée');
    }
```

Where I should add this line please?

```
return view('admin.candidats.edit', ['data' => $data]);
```

Here is my **edit.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="company-content">Sex</label>
  <select name="sexe" class="form-control" >
  <option value="Man"  {{ $data['sexe'] == "Man" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>Man</option>
   <option value="Women" {{ $data['sexe'] == "Women" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>Women</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So, my problem is in my Controller?

Comment: You need to give your options value attributes. `<option value="man">Man</option>`, If you don't want women by default you can also add an empty option at the beginning that is disabled like your first example just make it disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for  laravel from controller return view with data like

```
return view('edit', ['data' => $data]);

<select name="sexe" class="form-control" >
        <option value="Man"  {{ $data['sexe'] == "Man" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>Man</option>
          <option value="Women" {{ $data['sexe'] == "Women" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>Women</option>
        </select>
```

and for php

```
<select name="sexe" class="form-control" >
        <option value="Man"  {{ $_GET['sexe'] == "Man" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>Man</option>
          <option value="Women" {{ $_GET['sexe'] == "Women" ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>Women</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Is it possible to make this in Laravel?

Comment: yes when edit the form and return view with data like return view('edit', ['data' => $data]); than instead of  $_GET['sexe'] you can set like $data['sexe']. please see the edited answer

Comment: I have edited my first message... In my Controller I should put where return view('edit', ['data' => $data]); ??? On my function edit or update??? Thank you

Comment: yes exactly in edit because you have to show selected when you open edit from.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're POSTing your data in a form, and have included values as suggested by @Second2None, you need to tell your form to select the relevant option.

```
<option<?php if ($_POST['sexe'] == 'man') echo " selected"; ?>>Man</option>
```

Comment: I don't find the same procedure in laravel